# Keeps jumping back to start of Sub as soon as it completes first iteration in the nested loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, nested-loops

Very new to VBA coding. I inserted a Text Box (Active Control X) in my worksheet. Wrote a code to import data from MS Access database and save that data to an array. Later I am trying to print that array in the text box for user to see. but everytime my code enters the nested part of For loop, the running iteration of sub jumps back to the start of the code. Code than runs for multiple times make multiple SQL queries and excel crashes. I am not sure why code is jumping back to start of the sub?

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    Dim sQuery As String
    Dim ReturnData() As Variant
    'Clear existing data in statuses area
    Dim rngClearArea As Range
    Dim wsFleetio As Worksheet
        
    Set wsFleetio = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")
    Dim Farm As String
    
    Farm = wsFleetio.Range("B1").Value
    'Set rngClearArea = FindTag(wsFleetio, "$Vehicle Status", 2, 0).Resize(1000, 4)
    'rngClearArea.ClearContents
    
    'Build query
    sQuery = "SELECT [KillDate], [FarmName], [LoadType] FROM Loads WHERE ([FarmName] = '" & Farm & "' AND [KillDate] >= DateAdd('yyyy', -1, Date()))"
    
    ReturnData = GetMerlinData(sQuery)
    Dim leng As Integer
    leng = UBound(ReturnData, 2)
    
    Dim FarmData(500, 2) As Variant
    Dim m As Integer
    
    For m = 0 To UBound(ReturnData, 2)
        FarmData(m, 0) = ReturnData(0, m)
        FarmData(m, 1) = ReturnData(1, m)
        FarmData(m, 2) = ReturnData(2, m)
    Next
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(ReturnData, 2)
        For j = 0 To 2
            
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & FarmData(i, j) & "---"
        
        Next j
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & vbCrLf
    Next i

End Sub
```

After running the first iteration of j, code jumps back to start of the code. I want it to run normally but not sure what the error is

Comment: You need to disable events and re-enable  after. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.enableevents

Comment: @Warcupine Tried.. but still facing same issue.. everytime code encounters TextBox1.Text it jumps right back to the start of code.

Comment: At the top of the sub `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the end of the sub `Application.EnableEvents = True`.

Comment: @Warcupine Yup I added event handlers right at the top and bottom of the code, but still facing same issue.

Comment: Does `GetMerlinData` have anything that calls this sub or changes the text box?

Comment: @Warcupine I don't think its the GetMerlinData function... It only downloads data from a MS access database.. I tried running the code after removing the TextBox1.Text line and just using debug.pring to see if I am getting the information back and code runs smoothly.. Only when I add TextBox1.Text line in, is it breaks.

Comment: I am trying to display the information I am getting back from the database in the text box (Active X Control).

Comment: then you did something wrong with disabling events, if it is recursing when you modify the textbox it has to be the event.

Comment: very new to these vba forms. I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong. Not even sure if i am adding the code in correct sub.

Comment: Do you need to use on change event  .? That triggers on every letter entered. Would a command button not be better ?

Comment: @CDP1802 I have to show data as a table in text box. not sure how command button can help me out here. Do you know of any example codes that can enlighten me. Thank you for all the help

Comment: Move your code from the text box onchange event into a command button click event. No need to disable/enable events then.

Comment: This code is the cause:  TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & FarmData(i, j) & "---", as it triggers TextBox1_Change() event.

Comment: @CDP1802 I moved the code to command button and it worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a second TextBox, TextBox2  and use it in the loop: TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text & ...